# Disappearing variable in parallel computations

Tags: parallelization, procedural-programming

I have a problem with parallel computations. When I try to evaluate formula like this:

```
Do[m[i]=2,{i,1,10}]
```

and then I try to call for instance `m[1]` I get as an output `2`, so everything is all right. But when I do parallel computations and use the formula

```
Parallelize[Do[m[i] = 2, {i, 1, 10}]]
```

and then call the argument `m[1]` I get as an output `m[1]`, so *Mathematica* doesn't want to store my variable in the memory. If anyone has an idea why *Mathematica* behaves like this, please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are changing the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html?q=DownValues) of `m` inside your `ParallelDo` you have to share them among the parallel kernels using [`SetSharedFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetSharedFunction.html?q=SetSharedFunction) first:

```
SetSharedFunction[m]

Parallelize[Do[m[i] = 2, {i, 1, 10}]]

m[1]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

---

As you refer to `m` as a variable, something like

```
m = ConstantArray[0, 10]
SetSharedVariable[m]
Parallelize[Do[m[[i]] = 2, {i, 1, 10}]]
m[[1]]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

might be more appropriate.
But probably trying to ovoid using `Do` might be the better solution in that case:

```
m = ParallelTable[2, {i, 1, 10}];
```

Comment: +1 for `ParallelTable`; in Mathematica you want to try and use functional language, not procedural language

Answer (score 2):

This is not likely a practical approach, but it illustrates whats going on:

```
 Clear[x];
 ParallelDo[x[i] = i^2, {i, 1, 10}];
```

as noted the global `x` has not been defined, however each of our kernels retains the definition:

```
 ParallelEvaluate[{$KernelID, DownValues[x]}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

as a bit of a kludge we can pull the values back to global like this:

```
 Set @@@ ReleaseHold@Flatten@ParallelEvaluate@DownValues@x;
 x[#] & /@ Range[10]
```

> {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100}

similarly for lists:

```
 a = ConstantArray[0, 10];
 ParallelDo[a[[i]] = i^2, {i, 1, 10}];
 ParallelEvaluate[{$KernelID, a}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
 a=Total@ParallelEvaluate[a]
```

> {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100}